# cut section method

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I am asked to find the member force of AB and DE 
[image: fgfg]
[image: 32323]
I make an imaginary cut of the question and consider the upper part of the cut . Bur , i didnt get the same ans provided . However , when i consider the lower section of the cut , i get the same ans with the book . Anything wrong with my working ? 
Taking moment about A = 20(4) +30cos45 (3) + DE(4) = 0 , DE = -35.9 upwards

btw , the vertical reaction at a is 51.3 kN upwards , at E , vertical reaction = 35.9 kN upwards , and 21.2kN to the left ...

Comment: Why doesn't BE cause a moment around A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments to your question, you forgot to include the moment due to the internal force in BE.